# How to make projections of selected attributes in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have Coordinate model with many markers embedded_in User model. How to extract attributes without _ids so that on output display only each lng and lat?

structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc000009" ),
  "name" : "test",
  "coordinates" : [ 
    { "lng" : 16.86783310009764,
      "lat" : 52.38353842845282,
      "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000a" ) }, 
    { "lng" : 16.85787674023436,
      "lat" : 52.40972501601293,
      "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000b" ) }, 
    { "lng" : 16.92276474072264,
      "lat" : 52.40071858320756,
      "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000c" ) }, 
    { "lng" : 16.90182205273436,
      "lat" : 52.38270020105396,
      "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000d" ) }, 
    { "lng" : 16.96705337597655,
      "lat" : 52.410661698108,
      "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000e" ) }, 
    { "lng" : 16.89495559765624,
      "lat" : 52.42773236584494,
      "_id" : ObjectId( "4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000f" ) } ] }
```

e.g.

```
= debug @user.coordinates.to_json
```

gives:

```
--- ! '[{"_id":"4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000a","lat":52.383538428452816,"lng":16.86783310009764},{"_id":"4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000b","lat":52.40972501601293,"lng":16.85787674023436},{"_id":"4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000c","lat":52.40071858320756,"lng":16.92276474072264},{"_id":"4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000d","lat":52.382700201053964,"lng":16.90182205273436},{"_id":"4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000e","lat":52.410661698108,"lng":16.967053375976548},{"_id":"4e9f418f1e7bf20fbc00000f","lat":52.42773236584494,"lng":16.894955597656235}]'
```

expected:

```
--- ! '[{"lat":52.383538428452816,"lng":16.86783310009764},{"lat":52.40972501601293,"lng":16.85787674023436},{"lat":52.40071858320756,"lng":16.92276474072264},{"lat":52.382700201053964,"lng":16.90182205273436},{"lat":52.410661698108,"lng":16.967053375976548},{"lat":52.42773236584494,"lng":16.894955597656235}]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [except](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M000049)

```
 @user.coordinates.to_json(:except => '_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer returns data you wished. I would suggest though to use `without` against mongoid query so you actually do not fetch the data from DB, which is ideal.

```
@user.coordinates.without('_id').to_json(:except => '_id')
```